# In 3D space, how do I calculate a point at a certain height, that is linear with 2 other known points?

Tags: math, vector, 3d

**background**

I am working on a 3d game, where I need to transfer my mouse-input to a certain height in the 3d world, so I can move a unit across a surface.

This is done from the perspective of a tilted camera (45 degress tilted). the playcanvas API supplies me with a function on my camera, which can translate my mouse input on the 2d screen, into the 3d world using a set depth.

when I set my depth to 0, I get the exact coordinates of my camera (which in this case is (0,80,80), and if I set the depth to 100, I get ~(0.09, 11.52, 7.06)...

I need a way to figure out either the coordinates where the line between the two points hits the height (y-axis of 2), OR I could find a way to calculate the depth I need to supply the camera in order to get back the coordinates I need

**which leads me to:**

I have 2 coordinates in 3d space: let's say p1(0, 80, 80) and p2(0.09, 11.52, 7.06).

I want to figure out how to calculate a 3rd point, where y = 2. This point should be aligned with the 2 other points.

Any suggestions to how I can achieve this? I am looking for a solution with as few calculations as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to write a family of equations that describes all of the points in space that are collinear with p1 and p2.

```
x = x1*t + x2*(1-t)
y = y1*t + y2*(1-t)
z = z1*t + z2*(1-t)
```

... Where x1,y1,z1 are the coordinates of p1, ditto for p2, and `t` is any real number.

We can find the coordinates of our particular desired point by solving for `t`. We know that y = 2, so we'll rearrange that equation.

```
y = y1*t +y2 - y2*t
y - y2 = y1*t - y2*t
y - y2 = (y1 - y2)*t
(y - y2) / (y1 - y2) = t
t = (y - y2) / (y1 - y2)
```

Now that you know t, you can plug it into the two remaining equations to get your x and z values.